# EventAggregator for Java?

Tags: java, prism, eventaggregator

Is there an equivalent of Microsoft's Prism EventAggregator for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Microsoft's event aggregator and wrote it in Java. I'll try to put it on sourceforge or project kenai... When I'll have time and motivation.

Answer (score 0):

I think JMS with intermediate aggregator component could do the trick.